# Resteasy / Spring Security + Oauth 2.0 - error 404

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, resteasy

I'm trying to build a REST server/provider using Resteasy and Spring and wanted to secure some of the API using OAuth 2. As far as I understand, I should make the API expose an URI to generate the OAuth token (e.g. /oauth/token) and then use that to access the secured part.

Below is the code where I use Spring Security along with its OAuth2 support and I try to expose a single /oauth/token URI while protecting /ws/v1/oauth/**. When I try to access any of those URIs without sending credentials, I get the security "Bad Credentials request" (as I would expect), but when I try to actually input corret credentials on the /oauth/token URI (through a POST method) I am met with an HTTP 404 error.

My web.xml code.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring-context.xml
        classpath:database-context.xml
        classpath:security-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- RestEasy Bootstrap -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring Bootstrap -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- RestEasy Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- OAuth2 / Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And my security context. (which I found in an example here in stackoverflow and adapted a little)

```
<oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="clientAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="rest_server" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client" authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" 
            authorities="ROLE_READ" secret="1234567890" />
    <oauth:client client-id="password_client" authorized-grant-types="password" 
            authorities="ROLE_READ" secret="1234567890" />
</oauth:client-details-service>


<http pattern="/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/ws/v1/oauth/**" access="ROLE_READ" method="GET" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="false" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="400000" />
    <property name="refreshTokenValiditySeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="theRealm" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="theRealm/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>


<bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />


<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

I saw some similar problems where Spring Security was unable to register the http paths to the context because it wasn't being passed, but I have no idea how to do it in my Web.xml because I use SpringContextLoaderListener instead of ContextLoaderListener (which seems to be present in all the examples / problems I found).

Any tips on how to get this 404 error to go away?

EDIT - Just to clarify, I tested the /oauth/token URL with both POST and GET

GET example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/token?client_id=the_client&client_secret=1234567890&grant_type=client_credentials
```

In both cases I get the bad credentials / error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TokenEndpoint` is a Spring MVC `@Controller` so you need a `DispatcherServlet` to handle the requests. That might mean you need to ditch the `ContextLoaderListener` completely (but I have no idea with the `SpringContextLoaderListener` is doing) and move your configuration to the servlet (example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/1.0.x/samples/oauth2/sparklr/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)). Luckily the default servlet mapping "/" appears to be open, so everything should just work if you get the servlet installed and loading your config file.

Comment: Thank you Dave! The problem was with the lack of servlets to get the /oauth/token mapping. Also had to add spring webmvc annotations to my context so the OAuth2 Handlers would be able to properly handle the token request.